# complicação ao abrir monodevelop pelo unit3d personal

Tags: unity3d, monodevelop

Estou tentando desenvolver um jogo. 
No Unit 3d crio um novo script, tanto em C#scrip quanto em javascript e, ao editar, o mesmo é aberto pelo standard assets example projects - microsoft visual studio.

Porem eu gostaria de configurar o Unit para abrir pelo Monodevelop.

OBS: na versão atual do site do Monodevelop só consegui baixar um executavel chamado XamarinStudio v 5.10.0.871-0

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Esse problema pode ser resolvido através de três etapas:

**Primeira Etapa:**

*Edit > Preferences > External Tools > External Script Editor*

Em seguida basta escolher a opção tal como está na imagem:

[image: Exemple Image]

Quando chegar a esta passo basta escolher a opção **MonoDevelop**.

**Segunda Etapa:**

Caso na primeira etapa, não tenha aparecido a hipótese MonoDevelop para escolha, terá de clicar onde diz **"Browse..."**, e ir a pasta onde tem instalado o MonoDevelop e escolher o executável dele.

**Terceira Etapa:**

Caso na Segunda etapa, não encontrar nem a pasta, nem o executável do MonoDevelop poderá ser por ter escolhido não o instalar durante a instalação do Unity3d, nesse caso terá de fazer o Download do MonoDevelop e intala-lo, depois terá de fazer a Segunda e a Primeira Etapa aqui descritas.

**Download do MonoDevelop:** [Cliquei Aqui!](http://www.monodevelop.com/)

Este Download apesar de dizer XamarinStudio, é o MonoDevelop normal, apenas tem haver com empresas e seus negocios, mas a sua funcionalidade é a do MonoDevelop normal, o IDE de C#, F# e etc. Caso depois de instalar fique com o nome de XamarinStudio ele terá as mesmas funções do MonoDevelop, logo pode fazer as Etapas tal como expliquei em que a unica coisa que mudará sao os nomes de MonoDevelop para XamarinStudio.

> **PS:** A opção que tiver um certo tal como está na imagem é a que está escolhida e seleccionada, no meu caso eu preferi o Visual Studio 2015, mas para ter o MonoDevelop, basta clicar nele.

Espero ter ajudado.